# why I can't use Async.Std?

Tags: ocaml

I have install async mod by opam:

when input this in shell:

```
opam install async
```

shell returns:

```
[NOTE] Package async is already installed (current version is 113.33.03)
```

When I use utop,first `#require "async";;`
then I can `open Async.Std`
but when I write a program a.ml with one line:

```
open Async.Std
```

When I build the program:

```
corebuild a.native
```

It tells me it can't find async:

```
Error:Unbound module Async
```

I don't know why. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `corebuild` program, that is just a script wrapping the `ocamlbuild` tool, needs to know which libraries are you going to use. The `corebuild` just adds the `core` library, but not `async` or anything else. So you need to specify which library you're using explicitly, e.g.,

```
corebuild -pkg async a.native
```

To put it simply, `-pkg` corresponds to the `#require` directive.